# How to fix UI change in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, user-interface, filter

In my Home page I have a search bar and imported favoritedList component which show all the user favorited cards.

The problem I have is when I unfavorited a particular card, for some reason all the cards are disappearing from the UI even though it did not delete the rest of the card in the backend.

And when I refresh the browser then, the rest of the cards show back up. I'm not sure where exactly is wrong in my logic so I'll be really appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this.getUserFavs$.pipe(switchMap(() => {
          return this.userService.getUser();
        }),
      )
      .subscribe((user: User) => {
        this.favorites = user.userFavorites;
        this.user = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));
        this.filterChanged();
        this.loading = false;
      });
    this.getUserFavs$.next();
  }

  refresh(): void {
    this.getUserFavs$.next();
  }

  filterChanged(searchText?: string) {
    if (!searchText) {
      return (this.favorites = this.user.userFavorites);
    }
    searchText = searchText?.toLowerCase();
    this.favorites = this.user.userFavorites.filter((item) => {
      return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });
  }
```

HTML

```
  <form class="search-form">
    <input #searchValue id="input-field" autocomplete="off"
      name="insightSearchFilter"[formControl]="inputCtrl" />


    <p class="hint" *ngIf="inputCtrl.value">
      <strong> {{ favorites?.length }} Search Result for </strong>
      <em>"{{ inputCtrl?.value }}".</em>
      <strong> The Results listed below are exact matches for your query.</strong>
    </p>
  </form>

  <div *ngIf="favorites.length > 0">
    <app-card-list [cards]="favorites" (refreshCardList)="refresh($event)"></app-card-list>
  </div>
```

Comment: When you unfavourite a card, do any errors show up in the console?

Comment: @Searnd, Hi not it didn't show up any erros or warning in the console.

Comment: Hmm could you try removing the `*ngIf` around your app-card-list? Do all the cards still disappear when you only unfavourite one?